# Appcelerator Titanium View Proxy Memory Management

Tags: memory-management, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

I've been struggling on how to handle memory allocations on my Titanium app (built for [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) [9.4MB], [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)[2.8MB] and MobileWeb[5.4MB].

I have created a widget which will be use to open views from a menu selection.

```
<Alloy>
  <Window id="mainWindow">
    <View id="menuView">
        <View id="vTop">
            <!-- Header goes here -->
            <TableView id="menuTable" />
        </View>
        <!-- footer message goes here -->
    </View>

    <View id="contentView">
        <View id="nav">
            <Label id="winTitle"/>

            <View id='leftButtonView'>
                <Label id="icoLeftButton" />
            </View>

            <View id='backButtonTitleView'>
                <Label id="icoBack" />
                <Label id="backButtonTitle" />
            </View>

            <View id='rightButtonView'>
                <Label id="icoRightButton" />
            </View>
        </View>

        <View id="mainView" layout="composite" />
    </View>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Sample usage of this widget:

[image]

I was able to reduce the memory allocations of views by following [this solution](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/116867/this-is-a-solution-to-your-memory-woes#answer-203729). I've applied this every time I open another view from menu selection.

(controller of my widget)

```
var memPool = Ti.UI.createWindow();
memPool.open();
memPool.hide();
memPool.close();

// Open view from menu selection
function openView(e) {
    var cbAdd = function() {    
        var ctrl = Alloy.createController(e["url"]);

        if (ctrl != null) {
            setWindowTitle(e["wTitle"]);
            setRightIco(ctrl.getRightIco());  //setting right label icon (IcoMoon font)

            $.setRightNavClick(ctrl.getRightNavCb());

            //Have to passed navGroup to be able to open other views
            ctrl.winMain.navGroup = $;

            //Close splash screen after layout
            ctrl.winMain.addEventListener("postlayout", postLayout);
            $.mainView.add(ctrl.winMain);

            ctrl.init();
            ctrl = null;    
        }
    };

    var cbRemove = function() {
        //Remove all children from mainView; fn [commonjs]
        fn.removeChildren($.mainView, cbAdd);
    };

    if ($.mainView.children.length > 0) {
        cleanUp($.mainView.children[0]);
        cbRemove();

    } else
        cbAdd();
}

function cleanUp(obj, cb) {
    memPool.open();
    memPool.hide();
    memPool.setZIndex(-1);
    memPool.add(obj);
    memPool.close();

    obj = null;
    if (cb != null) cb();
}
```

Checking the result on XCode Instruments:

[image]

`TiUIView` is always reduced everytime I open other views from menu but `TiUIViewProxy` doesn't.

Sample View to be open: (consist of widgets)

```
<Alloy>
<View id="winMain">
    <ScrollView id="form" layout="vertical">
        <Widget id="fperiod" src="ph.com.test.controls.period" top="10" />

        <Widget id="ftermid" src="ph.com.test.controls.key" label="Terminal No." top="20" />

        <Widget id="fofficeid" src="ph.com.test.controls.combobox" label="Branch" />

        <View id="btnReset" width="100%" height="50" layout="horizontal" top="20" bottom="20" backgroundColor="#B40026">
            <Label class="resetFilter" />
            <Label class="lblReset" />
        </View> 
    </ScrollView>
</View>
</Alloy>
```

The following are the references that help alot:

- http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/116867/this-is-a-solution-to-your-memory-woes#answer-203729
- http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/
- http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152656/tips-and-tricks-for-memory-management
- http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140852/quick-memory-question--tiuiview-vs-tiuiviewproxy
- http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/151989/should-i-null-objects-to-release-memory-in-alloy

### How to reduce the memory allocations of `TiUIViewProxy`? Do I have to also cleanup the views of widgets from its controller?

I have tried to cleanup the views of my widgets from its controller. Then, the `TiUIViewProxy` is somewhat reduced as per checking it on XCode Instruments but my problem is that my app suddenly crashes. I don't know why. Or I'm not just doing it right. Sample clean up function from my widget:

```
$.cview.remove($.formItemLabel);
$.cview.remove($.lblValue);
$.mView.remove($.cview);

//nulling controller variables goes here
mData = null;
animateLeft = null;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really great article on memory management, I follow these guidelines for my own development purposes and highly recommend you read through this.

[Memory Management](http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/)

http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/